# onOptionItemSelected is not excuting on android

Tags: android, menuitem

i was using a menu item and the menu items click event listener is not working heres the code i used

```
Public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu,menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

public boolean onOptionItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch(item.getItemId(){
        case R.id.menu_id:
            Log.d("Menu","menu clicked")
    }
}
```

This is the code but the `onOptionItemSelected` method is not executing and when hover over it it says the method is never used...what am i doing wrong and how can i solve it?

Comment: method name is wrong. Check below answer.. its `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method name is wrong in your code.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // your code goes here
}
```

this is the method to override.

Hope it'll help.

Comment: also, using `@Override` will allow IDE to signal issues like this to you.

Comment: Yes @John . Use `@Override` to know if method exists in super class.

Comment: sorry about the type error but in my code its in the correct spelling

Comment: If method is in correct spelling, then your IDE will never tell you about `method is never used`, Try adding `@Override` annotation to method